# mysql.server status and mysql.server stop stuck

Tags: macos, mariadb

i am trying to run mysql.server start in my macOS Ventura 13.6.3 ,but i am trying to run mysql.server stop and mysql.server status stuck

Can anybody help me narrow down why I'm getting this error? I'm new to terminal and mariadb, so I'm hoping it's just a silly error that I wasn't aware of.

> mysql.server start

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mariadb/11.2.2/bin/mysqld_safe: Deprecated program name. It will be removed in a future release, use 'mariadb-safe' instead
240114 03:03:10 mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/Weis-MacBook-Air.local.err'.
.240114 03:03:10 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
 SUCCESS!
```

> cat /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/Weis-MacBook-Air.local.err

````
2024-01-14 16:50:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2024-01-14 16:50:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2024-01-14 16:50:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-01-14 16:50:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 240114 16:50:31
2024-01-14 16:50:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
2024-01-14 16:50:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 47733; transaction id 16
2024-01-14 16:50:32 0 [Note] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mariadb/11.2.2/bin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete

240114 16:52:16 mysqld_safe Starting mariadbd daemon with databases from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.2.2-MariaDB source revision 929532a9426d085111c24c63de9c23cc54382259 as process 1911
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=47733
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments in 3 undo tablespaces are active.
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 47733; transaction id 14
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is disabled.
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240114 16:52:16
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2024-01-14 16:52:16 0 [Note] /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mariadb/11.2.2/bin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '11.2.2-MariaDB'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Homebrew```
````

Comment: what is the contents of `/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/Weis-MacBook-Air.local.err`?

Comment: appears to be running fine. Brew packaging need to be updated to remove warnings, but your instance is fine.

Answer (score 0):

After quick research onto this topic, there could be several potentional problems that are causing it:

To troubleshoot the issue:

1. **Restart Your Mac**: Occasionally, only rebooting your Mac can fix brief issues that could be impairing MySQL's performance.
2. **Safe Mode**: If you want to see if any third-party extensions or apps are the problem, you can boot your Mac into safe mode first. Press the Shift key and restart if your Mac is Intel-based. Holding down the power button on a Mac equipped with Apple Silicon will bring up startup options. Press the Shift key and select "Continue in Safe Mode" from there. [Explained here](https://macpaw.com/how-to/macos-ventura-problems)
3. Verify Power and Display: Make sure your Mac is powered on and the display is working properly. These factors can occasionally lead to problems that appear to be software-related but are actually hardware-related. [Explained here](https://setapp.com/how-to/fix-macos-ventura-problems)
4. Activity Monitor: To determine which processes are using a lot of
   CPU resources and may be influencing MySQL's performance, use
   Activity Monitor (available under Applications > Utilities). [Explained here](https://macpaw.com/how-to/macos-ventura-problems)

Use commands like `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start` for MySQL versions prior to 5.7, or `sudo launchctl load -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` for more recent versions, to start, stop, or restart MySQL on macOS. [Explained here](https://wpbeaches.com/restart-start-stop-mysql-server-from-command-line-macos-linux/)

If these fixes don't work, it could be worth contacting Apple Support, particularly if you think the issue might be connected to your Mac's specific configuration or the compatibility of macOS Ventura.

Comment: As its mariadb, `com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld` shouldn't be part of the solution. Part of this aren't brew, so careful what you pick.